# Matching nodes with variable and set number of relationship of many types

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a tree of nodes that is connected with the relationship types: `PARENT_OF` and `NEXT`, and need to match all nodes `n` starting from the root to a variable depth `num`. Nodes `n` need to be direct children that are reached through `PARENT_OF`.

(the depth increments only through relationships of type `PARENT_OF`)

I have writte the following query:

```
MATCH p=(:HeadArgument)-[:PARENT_OF|:NEXT*]->(node) 
WHERE ()-[:PARENT_OF]->(node) AND size(filter(x IN relationships(p) WHERE type(x) = 'PARENT_OF')) <= {num} 
RETURN node
```

But it's inefficient because it matches on paths of all depths first and then filters out all paths that are too long (which can be extremely long and too many). I need a query that only reaches to set depths like the following examples with wrong syntax: `()-[(:NEXT*|:PARENT_OF)*..{num}]-()` (adding up variable paths like regular expressions): `()-{([:NEXT*]-()-[:PARENT_OF])*..{num}}-()` or another way if you know of any other ways.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to constrain the number of :PARENT_OF relationships, while being freely able to traverse :NEXT relationships? In your graph will these relationships be in any order, such as ```(:HeadArgument)-[:PARENT_OF]->()-[:NEXT]->()-[:PARENT_OF]->()```?

Comment: Yes I need to constraint only the number of PARENT_OF relationships. I don't understand what you mean by order. Between every two PARENT_OF relationships there can be a variable number of NEXT relationships. If you mean the direction then it's unidirectional from the head starting.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to take terminal nodes. Then the path from the root to them. Then go along these paths, counting all the appropriate nodes:

```
MATCH (R:HeadArgument)
MATCH (E) WHERE NOT (E)-[:NEXT|PARENT_OF]->()
WITH R, E
MATCH path = (R)-[:NEXT|PARENT_OF*]->(E)
WITH relationships(path) as edges
WITH REDUCE(nds=[], e in edges | 
            nds + CASE WHEN size(nds)<={num} AND type(e)='PARENT_OF' 
                       THEN endNode(e) 
                       ELSE [] 
                  END
     ) as nds
UNWIND nds as n
RETURN distinct n as node
```

Comment: But isn't this method as slow as (if not slower than) my attempt? The tree contains tens of thousands of nodes, and all that I'm interested in are the first few levels, so matching on all leaves and all paths leading to them could take up to 1000 times longer than stopping at a specific level. Anyway thanks for taking your time to write me an answer :)